# Using ssh with single command to execute remote binary

Tags: ssh, bash

I want to start a binary on Machine A from Machine B and wait for it to exit.

Machine B runs the following script:

```sh
ssh user@machineA bash -ic /bin/something
```

bash then aborts with `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`.

The binary runs correctly if executed directly on Machine A.

How do I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with ssh.

You are trying to run an executable compiled for a different architecture than Machine B is.

If you run `file` on the binary, it should tell you what architecture it is compiled for

You could either get(or compile) a binary that works for Machine B's architecture, or try to get some kind of emulator.

Without the kind of binary it is, I can't give any recommendations